How can I get the value of "power on time(POH)" of a sata disk with ata passthrough？
I want to get smart imformation of a sata disk attached to raid card through ata passthrough. I find that smartmontools use the funciton bool sat_device::ata_pass_through() to get my disk's smart values when I execute the command sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb -d megaraid,29.
bool sat_device::ata_pass_through(const ata_cmd_in & in, ata_cmd_out & out)

The struct cdb in the function above is the same as what I saw in this ata passthrough document link .
But I find that I can only use the api which is similar to
bool csmi_ata_device::ata_pass_through(const ata_cmd_in & in, ata_cmd_out & out)
in the source code of smartmontools. This function utilizes a 14-byte structure named fis.
And it fills the fis structure in this way
  {
    unsigned char * fis = pthru.bCommandFIS;
    const ata_in_regs & lo = in.in_regs;
    const ata_in_regs & hi = in.in_regs.prev;
    fis[ 0] = 0x27; // Type: host-to-device FIS
    fis[ 1] = 0x80; // Bit7: Update command register
    fis[ 2] = lo.command;
    fis[ 3] = lo.features;
    fis[ 4] = lo.lba_low;
    fis[ 5] = lo.lba_mid;
    fis[ 6] = lo.lba_high;
    fis[ 7] = lo.device;
    fis[ 8] = hi.lba_low;
    fis[ 9] = hi.lba_mid;
    fis[10] = hi.lba_high;
    fis[11] = hi.features;
    fis[12] = lo.sector_count;
    fis[13] = hi.sector_count;
  }

So I want to know how to populate this structure so that it can obtain the SMART information I need. Or where can I learn some document relative.
What I only know is to set
    fis[ 0] = 0x27; // Type: host-to-device FIS
    fis[ 1] = 0x80; // Bit7: Update command register
    fis[ 2] = 0xB0; // ATA_CMD_SMART


When using a RAID card? This seems likely to be card specific. SATA (Serial ATA) is not SCSI. That would be SAS (Serial Attached SCSI). The Broadcom documentation says (in part) For SATA drives, run smartctl -a -d sat+megaraid,device-id Does sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb -d sat+megaraid,29 change anything?

@Elliott Frisch No changes,  the output is same as the command without sat+, and it still calls the funciton  bool sat_device::ata_pass_through(const ata_cmd_in & in, ata_cmd_out & out) . I think maybe I should learn something about fis.

Good instincts.

@Elliott Frisch  Much thanks! I'll learn it later!

In this document , section

7.53.6 SMART READ DATA - B0h/D0h, PIO data-in

told me that I should set FIS[2] = 0xB0; FIS[3] = 0xD0; FIS[5] = 0x4F; FIS[6] = 0xC2; to read SMART DATA
And refer to drivedb.h in the source code of smartmontools, you may find some structure definitions of SMART raw data
{ "DEFAULT",
"-", "-",
"Default settings",
"-v 1,raw48,Raw_Read_Error_Rate "
"-v 2,raw48,Throughput_Performance "
"-v 3,raw16(avg16),Spin_Up_Time "
"-v 4,raw48,Start_Stop_Count "
"-v 5,raw16(raw16),Reallocated_Sector_Ct "
"-v 6,raw48,Read_Channel_Margin,HDD "
"-v 7,raw48,Seek_Error_Rate,HDD "
"-v 8,raw48,Seek_Time_Performance,HDD "
"-v 9,raw24(raw8),Power_On_Hours "
"-v 10,raw48,Spin_Retry_Count,HDD "
"-v 11,raw48,Calibration_Retry_Count,HDD "
"-v 12,raw48,Power_Cycle_Count "
...

After comparison, I used int poh = rawSMARTData[21] << 16 | rawSMARTData[20] << 8 | rawSMARTData[19]; to get the power-on time
